# What's a good method for verifying an Azure Table Insert operation?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

So far I've been relying on the `TableResult.HttpStatusCode = 204` as a positive result from an `Insert` operation as per:

[TableResult.HttpStatusCode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableresult.httpstatuscode?view=azure-dotnet)

I get a `200` if the entity exists already and a `204` on a successful insert operation. I've also tried using the `echoContent` parameter on the `TableOperation` as per:

[TableOperation.Insert Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.insert?view=azure-dotnet)

The `echoContent` doesn't return anything in my case so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm chasing unicorns. I wasn't sure if the `echoContent` just sends back the data you sent to it or if it actually echo's back the written entity.

Is there a better way to validate? Am I relying on the REST api of Azure Table storage too much or is this all we have?

Comment: If you're doing an insert operation and the entity already exists, then you should get back `Conflict (409)` status code. Are you sure you're getting back `200` status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually doing a read operation first, then evaluating the result to see if a duplicate exists earlier on in my code. The insert operation performed without checking first did indeed return a `409`, however this was found after debugging an exception caused by inserting over top of an existing entity.

My first bit of code was a much less frequent activity, and more important that I check for a duplicate entity which is why I did the read first, then the check, then an insert.

My latter code was from an API which is taking in a considerable amount of data and I didn't want to burden the transaction with a lookup & compare before the insert.

To solve for this, I set a try/catch block to watch for the specific exception type of `409`:

```
catch (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException e) when (e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == 409)
        {
            TableResult tableResult = new TableResult();
            tableResult.HttpStatusCode = e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode;
            tableResult.Result = e.Message;
            return tableResult;
        }
```

Since my method was returning a `TableResult` type, I had to format a new `tableResult` to send back to the caller. Using a switch statement on the caller I was able to handle the various scenarios (success/exception).