# When does Insert operation in Azure Table Client return something else but 204?

Tags: c#, azure, insert, azure-table-storage

This is (roughly) how I insert entities in the Azure Table:

```cs
public async Task<bool> InsertAsync(string tableName, T entity)
{
    var table = _cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
    await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    var operation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
    var tableResult = await table.ExecuteAsync(operation);
    return tableResult.HttpStatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
}
```

Looks like this is more or less the [way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543741/whats-a-good-method-for-verifying-an-azure-table-insert-operation). I am writing tests for that and so I just got curious, what should I do to get not 204 in `tableResult.HttpStatusCode`?

Inserting bad entities throws exceptions, inserting same entities throws exceptions - I am **not** talking about that. I want to know what else can status code be assigned to.

Comment: does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-error-codes) help?

Comment: Well... That's a general reference for all the operations returning table result, whereas I am talking about a particular thing. As I mention, e.g. inserting conflicting entity does not end up in 409 status code in the table result but instead throws `StorageException` with status code = 409 in the `RequestInformation` of the exception.

Comment: I tried inserting an entity that is too large but it also just throws another `StorageException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For successful [`Insert Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity) operation, you can expect to get either `204 (No Content)` or `201 (Created)` status code. The status code depends on the value of the `Prefer` header.

If the Prefer header is set to return-no-content, then a successful operation returns status code 204 (No Content). If the Prefer header is not specified or if it is set to return-content, then a successful operation returns status code 201 (Created).

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity#response

If for some reason the operation fails, SDK is designed to throw an exception (of type StorageException) as that operation has failed.

Comment: Alright, now the `TableResult` makes at least some sense.